# Did playing Hearthstone during the beta grant any benefits that can't be matched by playing the game later?

Tags: achievements, hearthstone

Playing Hearthstone during the beta might have granted players more experience as well as more cards to play with. These are both benefits that may be matched by playing more later. However, some games grant beta players exclusive content such as gear or achievements that players get to keep even after the beta. To players that didn't play the beta, this content would then be [lost forever](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LostForever). Did playing the Hearthstone beta grant beta players any such content?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a few pieces of exclusive content thusfar in Hearthstone. The first is a [golden 'Gelbin Mekkatorque' card](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Gelbin_Mekkatorque), that could be earned by using real money to make a purchase in Hearthstone while it was in the beta.

> The golden version of this card is no longer obtainable. It was previously obtained by spending real money in the store during the game's beta test, prior to the full release of the game.

In addition, [golden 'Elite Tauren Chieftain'](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Elite_Tauren_Chieftain) was only earnable through purchasing a ticket to Blizzcon 2013, and thus also can't be earned any longer.

However, the normal version of each of these cards are still both able to be earned through crafting them.

Card backs will likely be exclusive to each season and event, such as the ones earned through levels in ranked on specific seasons, but thusfar, I haven't seen anything specific about this yet.

Comment: Small correction; Gelbin and ETC aren't in packs

Comment: But during the beta Gelbin got significantly nerfed from OP card to useless card.

Comment: Nerfed or not, it still irks me that I never found this out during the beta, and missed out on a card. I buy packs now, so I may as well have bought one during testing :)

Comment: @BazzPsychoNut He's still a very fun card, and is decent in the right deck. I have three different creature spam decks that run him because, for the most part, he's pretty good if you are the only person with creatures. Unless he brings Poultreyizer ><

Comment: @MattThrower During the beta, I believe he was advertised as being earn-able in the actual client himself if you went to the shop.

Comment: @waterseas That's just it: I never went to the shop. There didn't seem much point in investing in something that wasn't finished yet :) My loss.

Answer (score 9):

The only thing from the beta that can't be acquired anymore is the golden version of Gelbin Mekkatorque (for buying something with real money during the beta). The normal version of this card can still be crafted.

Also there is Elite Tauren Chieftain of which the golden version can't be acquired any more. That was granted by buying a Blizzcon 2013 ticket.